# Preserving sign during a masking operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a 16 bit word (short). I would like to take the lower 13 bits and save them in a new short while preserving the sign (i.e if bit 12 is a 1, then I want bits 13-15 in the new word to also be 1, but if bit 12 is a 0, then I want bits 13-15 in the new word to be 0).

For example, if I have

```
short a = 0xDADD // 0b1101101011011101
short b = 0xFADD // 0b1111101011001110
```

or

```
short a = 0xABCD // 0b1010101111001101
short b = 0x0BCD // 0b0000101111001101
```

I can do it with conditionals, but I'd like to try and avoid that if I can and stick to as few bitwise operations as possible. Another option would be to do a 3-bit shift to the left followed by a 3-bit arithmetic right shift, but it's my understanding that most C compilers interpret the `>>` operator as a logical shift. Is there a way to force an arithmetic shift?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `(x & 0x1fff ^ 0x1000) - 0x1000`. After masking the low 13 bits, this flips bit 12 and subtracts 4096 (2<sup>12</sup>).

To see this works, consider value *b* (0 or 1) for bit 12 and value *c* (0 to 4095) for bits 11 to 0. In a 13-bit two’s complement representation, bit 12 represents −4096, so the represented value is −4096•*b* + *c*. Instead, in our wider integer type, we have 4096•*b* + *c*. Flipping *b* gives 4096•(1-*b*) + *c*, and then subtracting 4096 gives 4096•(−*b*) + *c* = −4096•*b* + *c*, which is the desired result.

Comment: To make this adjustable based on an arbitrary number of bits, you can compute all the constants in here based on the number of bits per [Bit Twiddling Hacks' variable-based (but otherwise identical) solution to "Sign extending from a variable bit-width"](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#VariableSignExtend). Ideally wrapping in a macro, since `(x & ((0x1 << b) - 1) ^ (0x1 << (b - 1))) - (0x1 << (b - 1))` dropped inline into your code repeatedly would get pretty ugly (the equivalent macro, with proper parentheses use, is even uglier, but at least you only write it once).

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to "sign extending from a constant bit width", for which [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#FixedSignExtend) provides an optimized solution:

Essentially, you just declare yourself a `struct` with a field containing the expected number of bits, and channel your assignments through a field on such a struct. For your case, you'd just adapt it to the 13 bit case:

```
short a = ...;
short b;
struct {signed short x:13;} s;
b = s.x = a;
```

The advantage to this is that you don't try any actual bit-twiddling yourself (which might produce optimal code on architecture X, but terrible results on architecture Y), you just let the compiler determine the optimal solution for the target for you.

##### Example:

```
int main(void)
{
  short a;
  short b;
  struct {signed short x:13;} s;

  a = 0xDADD;
  b = s.x = a;

  printf("%04hx\n%04hx\n\n", a, b);

  a = 0xABCD;
  b = s.x = a;
  printf("%04hx\n%04hx\n", a, b);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzT6MsPzNFk6uaS0GhOCO/qEQh0RrOTAIzS4pKk0sUqosz0/NSU6AyFVaGxta1CsXWXEAViQq2CgYVLo4uLiD1SUBesV4FkEwEyxYUAa1K01BSNTDJqIjJg1IxeUo6Cok6CkmaSEY4OjljGoHLBIT@2v///yWn5SSmF//XLS5JsU3PKzU0BAA)

which outputs:

```
dadd
fadd
    
abcd
0bcd
```

---

If you're actually using C++ over C, a templated function makes this even easier (no manually rewriting it for each case, or using hacky unreliable macro-based code), using a template function:

```
template <typename T, unsigned B>
inline T signextend(const T x)
{
  struct {T x:B;} s;
  return s.x = x;
}
```

which simplifies the use case to:

```
short b = signextend<signed short, 13>(a);
```

Obviously, if you must use C for whatever reason, this is not an option, but template hacks like this are sometimes worth a switch even if you largely stick to C idioms.

Comment: The result of storing an out-of-range value in a signed integer (bit-field or otherwise) is implementation-defined, per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's pretty clever. My target processor does not have a C++ compiler currently, so I have to stick to C for now.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Hmm... Interesting. I'm not a standards expert, but yes, it does seem like the behavior isn't strictly guaranteed (reading *from* the bit-field is safe, writing to it might not be; the Bit Twiddling link is working with consistent fixed widths it seems). Not sure what behavior an implementation might choose instead, nor whether any existing implementations choose a different one, but that is something to check (perhaps by use of `static_assert` to get compile-time fail-fast behavior when the implementation does "the wrong thing", testing a dozen or so obvious boundary cases).